# Is there any possibility to adding a value beside expression in driven property?

Tags: drivers

Is there any possibility to adding a value beside expression in driven property? Formulas would be only in drivers window or not?

If I need add expression like:

```
self.location[0]+object.location[1]
```

< both value dependant

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A shortcut to [entering driver expressions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/introduction.html#expression) is to start with a `#` - so entering `#frame*0.1` will create a driver expression that sets the value to 1/10th of the current frame. You can then edit drivers using the graph editor in [driver mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#mode).

Using the `#` prefix works for some things that are available globally, like the current `frame` and some math functions - `sin()`, `log()`, `noise.random()` etc. To get a driver to depend on a transform channel or property, whether it is it's own property or another objects, you create [driver variables](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/drivers_panel.html#driver-variables) and use them in your expression.

[image: using driver variables]

To see a full list of functions available within drivers, enter `bpy.app.driver_namespace.keys()` into blenders [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/python_console.html).

You can also define your own functions and add them to the driver namespace as [shown here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#driver-namespace).

Comment: Thank you sambler, but this is not what I ask. Problem is that, if I have some expression in property I would like controll the property (animator) even the property is purple (default expresion color) but if i want to set some number it give me only expression as i show in my main question. So I would like to freely controll "expresioned" property without see the expression, only number.

Comment: @mrl you can't have both, you either use a driver that calculates the value or you manually keyframe the value. Note that you can have a driver read multiple custom properties that you can manually adjust. You can also create your own function which could use a custom property except on frame 125 where it calculates from other sources. You can also enter an expression without the # prefix and it will only be calculated at that time, but you are still limited to what properties you can access.

Comment: Thank you sabler. I asked because with expressions in after Effects it is possible. And I would like round the number I set. In blender I must use other options then.

Comment: @sambler I appreciate your insight, I've used drivers for years and never picked up on this method of input. Awesome nugget.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can...

You have to have an empty driver 1st... (Via manually create later single)

Then you have to use a slightly different format, but it works...

I have a cube named 'c1' & 'c2':

I added the following line to the "z" location for 'c1' and hit enter.

```
3.0 + bpy.data.objects['c2'].location[2]
```

It worked!

Comment: The problem with this though, is that it does not update, when you change the z position of `'C2'`, you have to enter back into the 'z' location property of `'C1'` and hit enter to force the update.

Comment: Thank you, can you please post preent creen of "You have to have an empty driver 1st... (Via manually create later single)" Because I dont understand what you mean. And the value of property will controll some animator, so i would like have only value in Z-location - nothing else. < it must be animable